# How to Implement Editable Grid

Tags: asp.net

I have one gridview with values in the below format

```
year  2001 2002 2003 2004 2005

 A      1    12    0    4    5

 B      6    17    2   0     2

 C      6    17    2   0     2

 E      6    17    2   0     2
```

I need to make the cells of the gridview to be editable except 1st row and column.1st row and  column values are taken from database.

Any one please help me in that

Answer (score 0):

Add the below as first column of the GridView, this one adds the edit button to all your grid view rows.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
```

Once you add the above all the databound gridview cells should be open for editing upon clicking the Edit link on the first column. In order to make the columns not editable set the ReadOnly property of the column to true like a below sample BoundField Column.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="year" ReadOnly="True" />
```

To update the edited cell value write the appropriate Update Command (query) to the  datasource or handle the DB update functionality under the RowUpdating event of the gridview.

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

One  way is there that take your first row of gridview as template field instead of bound field.